# How to split a string at a . to parse to an integer from user input? (ex. IP Address that will be formatted with the . already in it)

Tags: c#, ip-address, split

```
string strSeverIP = Console.ReadLine();
string serverIpAddress = String.Split(".", strSeverIP);
```

I'm trying to split this string at the period of server addresses so that I can parse each individual string into an integer. These integers will be inserted into an address format as numbers instead of text for comparison. The String.Split keeps erroring with "best overloaded method match 'string.Split(string[], System.StringSplitOptions)' has some invalid arguments." I'm not seeing where the problem is. I've looked at examples online and still can't find the problem. Thanks for those who have worked on the problem and I thank you for your patience. I'm not the best phraser and I don't think about what I've done to try the problem when I'm angry. Thanks for your patience again.

Comment: Change the code to this 
`var serverIpAddress = strSeverIP.Split('.');`

Comment: I have changed it to that now. It has gotten rid of my current problem but now serverIpAddress doesn't exist in the current context. @DJKRAZE

Comment: There is also an `IpAddress.Parse` Method you could have looked at as well next time do a simple google search Dustin there are tons of excellent answers and examples you could have found [MSDN: IPAddress.Parse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ipaddress.parse.aspx)

Comment: Dustin you need to provide more information / code than that.. if you are splitting the IP Address out just like you stated.. then where is the code that shows what you are trying to do after you split it..??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the string is a IP adress, it is better to use IPAddress class:

```
string inputStr = "10.30.0.72";
System.Net.IPAddress ipAddress;
if (System.Net.IPAddress.TryParse(inputStr, out ipAddress))
{
    byte[] addressByte = ipAddress.GetAddressBytes();
}
```

This will give `addressByte[4] = {10, 30, 0, 72}`.

Comment: addressByte[4] = {10,30, 0, 72}

Comment: How would I be able to put the addressByte back to a string? Just use the .ToString() function? @fanium

Comment: Yes. You can use byte.ToString() for each byte.

Answer (score 1):

```
string[] serverIpAddress = strSeverIP.Split('.');
int[] ips = new int[serverIpAddress.Length];
for (int i = 0; i < serverIpAddress.Length; ++i)
{
   if (!int.TryParse(serverIpAddress[i], out ips[i]))
      {
           //replace with whatever :)
           throw new Exception("Invalid ip!");
      }
}
```

Comment: This worked. Thank you. Send me a note. Will accept when I get home.